# XML string to c# object not returning data

Tags: c#, json, xml, deserialization

I have an XML string which i am needed to get data from but cannot seem to return any rows.
the string is:

```
"<Tables><Table SourceQuery=\"Transaction\"><Rows><Row><ShiftID></ShiftID><EmployeeID>ANDREW</EmployeeID></Row><Row><ShiftID></ShiftID><EmployeeID>ANDREW</EmployeeID></Row></Rows></Table><Tables>"
```

My code is:

```
var xmlText =
            "<Tables><Table SourceQuery=\"Transaction\"><Rows><Row><ShiftID></ShiftID><EmployeeID>ANDREW</EmployeeID><StartDateTime>02/11/2018 10:30:00</StartDateTime><EndDateTime>02/11/2018 19:00:00</EndDateTime><ShiftCost></ShiftCost><Break>30</Break><Location>Main Bar</Location><Type></Type></Row></Rows></Table></Tables>";

var stringReader = new StringReader(xmlText);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tables));
var neededObject =  serializer.Deserialize(stringReader) as Tables;
var rows = neededObject.Table.Rows.Row;
```

[image: two muppets]
Row is returning 0 rows

I'm sure there is a better way to get this data out that what i am currently doing (especially as its not working) but any advice would be appreciated. I assume its something wrong with my class structure.

In future, i will need to be able to get the sourceQuery from 'Table' so cannot just remove those

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you stuff a zero or other number in `ShiftID` or make that property a nullable int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the attribute to your class and properties.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Row")]
public class Row
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ShiftID")]
    public string ShiftID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "EmployeeID")]
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Rows")]
public class Rows
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Row")]
    public List<Row> Row { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Table")]
public class Table
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Rows")]
    public Rows Rows { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SourceQuery")]
    public string SourceQuery { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Tables")]
public class Tables
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Table")]
    public Table Table { get; set; }
}
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NRInC6)

Comment: isn't the `XmlElement` redundant when property name matches the xml element name?

Comment: Amazing that worked. I assumed the same at @selman but without those it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: You cheated by turning `ShiftId` into a string.

Comment: @Crowcoder I will guess `ShiftId` is string because there isn't fill value in `ShiftId` node.

Comment: @D-Shih and I will guess that's why it works  and has nothing to do with the xml attributes. I'll try it myself but I just wonder if there will be integral ShiftID at some point